# Line not exactly on the x-Axis

Tags: pgfplots, axis

My problem: The plotted line does not lie exactly on the axis...

Here is my output:

[image]

and here is the code to generate it:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ axis on top=true,
         axis x line=middle,
         axis y line=middle,
         inner axis line style={=>},
                 width=6cm,height=6cm,
                     ymin=0,ymax=1.2,
                     xmin=0,xmax=1.2,
                     axis line style = thick,
                     xtick={0,1},
                     ytick={0,1},
                 every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of     origin)},anchor=west},
         every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.north west)},above=0.5mm},
                 xlabel={$p$},
                 ylabel={$q$}]
\draw[line width=4, red] (0,0)--(100,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically to your question: could you develop a little bit more? Because, you post contains no question. Do you expect a vertical centring of the red line and the x-axis ?

Comment: Your line *does* lie exact on the x-axis. The bottom half of your line is outside of the plotting area. To use axis coordinates inside (a good idea anyway) the axis, you need to set compat version - e.g. `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`

Answer (score 4):

Border of diagram clip all outsize of diagram, so you see only half of line. To solve this problem, you have two possibilities:

- draw this line outside of diagram (see another answer)
- use option `\clip=false` in `axis` diagram

Since this line if far longer than diagram width you also need to define its lenght accordingly. One solution, where this line is drawn width `\addplot` is shown on the next MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} % <---

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ axis on top=true,
         axis lines=middle, % <---
         %inner axis line style={=>}, % not used
                 width=6cm,height=6cm,
                     ymin=0,ymax=1.2,
                     xmin=0,xmax=1.2,
                     %axis line style = thick,
                     xtick={0,1},
                     ytick={0,1},
                 every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}, anchor=west},
         every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.north west)},above=0.5mm},
                 xlabel={$p$},
                 ylabel={$q$},                 
                 clip=false % <---
                    ]
\addplot +[line width=4pt, no marks, red] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} %added
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ axis on top=true,
         axis x line=middle,
         axis y line=middle,
         inner axis line style={=>},
                 width=6cm,height=6cm,
                     ymin=-0.05,ymax=1.2,  %made ymin negative, to include red line
                     xmin=0,xmax=1.2,
                     axis line style = thick,
                     xtick={0,1},
                     ytick={0,1},
                 every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of     origin)},anchor=west},
         every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.north west)},above=0.5mm},
                 xlabel={$p$},
                 ylabel={$q$}]
\draw[line width=4, red] (0,0)--(1,0); %changed form 100 to 1
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot with red line]

Comment: Zarko's solution with `clip=false` is probably better for what you want. Notice the setting of compat makes your `\draw` with the correct axis coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Just move your line code before `axis` and outside of it:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=4pt, red] (0,0)--(100,0);
\begin{axis}[ axis on top=true,
         axis x line=middle,
         axis y line=middle,
         inner axis line style={=>},
                 width=6cm,height=6cm,
                     ymin=0,ymax=1.2,
                     xmin=0,xmax=1.2,
                     axis line style = thick,
                     xtick={0,1},
                     ytick={0,1},
                 every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of     origin)},anchor=west},
         every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.north west)},above=0.5mm},
                 xlabel={$p$},
                 ylabel={$q$}]
%\draw[line width=4pt, red] (0,0)--(100,0);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]